# How to groupby and unionize polygons in geopandas by a certain category?

Tags: group-by, geopandas

I'm trying to groupby polygons that belong to a certain block group which I can then use to make a visualization.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from dateutil.parser import parse 

import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon

shp = gpd.read_file("Data/SD_Census_Block_Groups.shp")

#Rename GEOID to bg_orig
shp = shp.rename({'GEOID': 'bg_orig'}, axis='columns')

shp.head(10)
```

Let's say I want to do a groupby of the geometry column with the column NAMELSAD which has the Block Group labels. So any row in a certain  Block Group will be unionized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for `dissolve`.

```py
result = shp.dissolve(by='NAMELSAD')
```

Reference: https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.dissolve.html#geopandas.GeoDataFrame.dissolve

Comment: Hi, I'm able to get a graph, but it's not showing me the seven distinct block groups.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: So I'm able to get a map of my county, but it's all the same color and its dividing it by individual census blocks. There are seven block groups, and I'm trying to get the seven distinct block groups that are made up of these individual census blocks to show up.